# GROUP BY with MAX() return wrong id of the rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, max, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the maximum used capacity for each order_product_id for each week when executing a request. The JOIN or SELECT variant in the WHERE clause does not work because max_capacity is repeated for some order_product_id's. My query returns the correct order_product_id and max_capacity for each week, but does not return the correct row ID.

```
CREATE TABLE `capacity_log` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_occurred` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`ip_address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`order_product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`serial` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`used_capacity` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`aux2` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`request` BLOB NULL,
`retry_count` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fetch_time` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`response` BLOB NULL,
`custom_fetch_time` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `user_id` (`order_product_id`))
```

My query:

```
SELECT  c.order_product_id, MAX(c.used_capacity) AS `max_capacity`
FROM capacity_log c
WHERE c.date_occurred < '2020-10-1' AND c.aux2 IS NULL 
GROUP BY
    YEAR(c.date_occurred), WEEK(c.date_occurred),
    c.order_product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You want entire rows, so aggregation is not what you are after. Instead, you need to filter. One option uses a subquery:

```
select c.*
from capacity_log c
where c.id = (
    select c1.id
    from capacity_log c1
    where  
        c1.date_occurred < '2020-10-1' 
        and c1.aux2 is null
        and c1.order_product_id = c.order_product_id
        and yearweek(c1.date_occurred) = yearweek(c.date_occurred)
    order by c1.used_capacity desc limit 1
)
```

We can optimize the `where` clause of the subquery like so:

```
    where  
        c1.date_occurred < '2020-10-1' 
        and c1.aux2 is null
        and c1.order_product_id = c.order_product_id
        and c1.date_occurred >= c.date_occurred - interval weekday(c.date_occurred) day
        and c1.date_occurred <  c.date_occurred - interval weekday(c.date_occurred) day + interval 7 day
```

For performance, you want an index on `(order_product_id, aux2, date_occurred, used_capacity, id)`.

Comment: The pre-edit version returns exactly what I want, but when I test with a database that has more data, it takes a long time. Any ideas?