# MariaDB query optimization

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

Is there any option to optimize this query. It has been running for almost 4 hours and I still have no result. The current row count of the table is 282359

```
select c.id
from capacity_log c
where c.id = (
    select c1.id
    from capacity_log c1
     where  
        c1.date_occurred < '2020-10-1' 
        and c1.aux2 is null
        and c1.order_product_id = c.order_product_id
        and yearweek(c1.date_occurred) = yearweek(c.date_occurred)
    order by c1.used_capacity desc limit 1
)
```

The idea is to take the id of the column of the maximum used capacity for each week for each order_product_id

```
CREATE TABLE `capacity_log` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_occurred` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`ip_address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`order_product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`serial` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`used_capacity` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`aux2` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`request` BLOB NULL,
`retry_count` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fetch_time` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`response` BLOB NULL,
`custom_fetch_time` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `user_id` (`order_product_id`))




    +------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
    | id   | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                            | rows   | Extra                       |
    +------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
    |    1 | PRIMARY            | c     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                           | 390573 | Using where                 |
    |    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c1    | ref  | user_id       | user_id | 4       | web_license.c.order_product_id |    134 | Using where; Using filesort |
    +------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

version: 10.1.47-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. I have a comment. When you ask a question about query optimization, you should include the definition of your table so we don't have to guess at indexes or data types. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE capacity_log` in a mysql client, and include the result in your question. Also use `EXPLAIN` to report the current optimization strategy for your query, and include that. Please post these as text, not as screenshots. Finally, include the result of `SELECT @@version;` because the best answer may depend on features in recent version of MySQL.

Comment: I suggested optimizations in the answer I posted to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475993/group-by-with-max-return-wrong-id-of-the-rows), did you try them?

Comment: You're using MariaDB 10.1 but to do the query you want you should use [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/), which are supported in MariaDB 10.2. I suggest you upgrade. Besides, [MariaDB 10.1 is now past its end of life](https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy), so you should upgrade anyway.

Comment: The option you suggested returns a different result than the 'non-optimized option' @GMB

Comment: @ПламенЦанов: that's suprising. Are you able to provide a [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5) that demonstrates the problem (preferably as a comment to the other question)?

Answer (score 0):

Using window functions, which require you to upgrade to MariaDB 10.2 or later:

```
select t.id
from (
    select id, row_number() over (partition by order_product_id,
        yearweek(date_occurred) order by used_capacity desc) as rownum
    from capacity_log
    where date_occurred < '2020-10-1'
    and aux2 is null
) as t
where t.rownum = 1;
```

I think the following index would help this query:

```
alter table capacity_log add index (aux2, date_occurred, order_product_id, used_capacity);
```

But I don't use MariaDB so I have not tested this.